# Getting data from View using CrudRepository

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

For this question,I am not looking for a solution, but looking for a direction from where I can take myself ahead, hence not sharing any code.

I am preparing a REST API and I have postgresql database setup locally, which has 2 tables and one view from those 2 tables.

Normally when I want to get any data from DB, I use following code(for the sake of clarity):

**DataRepository class:**

```
public interface DataRepository extends CrudRepository<Data, String>{}
```

**DataService class:**

```
@Service
public class DataService {
    @Autowired
    private DataRepository repo;
    public Data getData(String id){
        return repo.findById(id).orElse(null);
    }
}
```

**DataController class:**

```
@RestController
public class DataController{
    @Autowired
    private DataService service;
    @RequestMapping("/{id}")
    public Data getData(String id){
        return service.getData(id);
    }
}
```

**Data class:**

```
@Entity
public class Data{
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;

    //respective getter and setter methods
}
```

**Now I want to retrieve data from a view, so, what should be the approach for that?**

**Should we use the same approach of creating Model, Service, Ctonroller and Repository classes?**

**Can we use CrudRepository to achieve the same?**

I searched in a lot of places, but didn't find anything useful.

Let me know if anyone has any clue on this.

Comment: Maybe you like https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-rest

Comment: I actually saw that one, there it describes the basic process of using CrudRepository interface and tells how to connect to db like mysql, mongodb.
But what I am actually looking for is retrieving data from a VIEW not a table.

Answer (score 2):

The reading methods of a `CrudRepository` should work fine with a view. For the writing methods, the view needs to be updatable[enter link description here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/mysql-5.1-en/view-updatability.html).

If you only want to read, but not to write to the repository, you can create a `ReadOnlyRepository` by copying the source code of the `CrudRepository` and removing all the writing methods.

Note that JPA will still try to persist changes made to managed entities.
To avoid that and also avoid the cost of dirty checking you can [mark your entities as immutable](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-immutable) if you are using Hibernate.

Comment: And to use additional filters like , where id='1' and category='A'
should I use @Query annotation ?

Comment: You can use the full Spring Data JPA feature set: `@Query` annotation, derived queries, specifications, custom methods.

Comment: So, I am creating new Model, Service and Controller classes, like we normally do when getting data from table.
But in the end will jpa be able to know that it has to look data in table and not in view.
Also, we can change table name by using @Table annotation above our Model class, what to do if we want to customize the view name ?

Comment: Yes, apart from possible limitations when writing to a view a view looks just like a table to JPA (and really any database user).